# How to know what underlying algorithm mathematica function is using?

Tags: image, filtering, implementation-details

For example `Blur`, the documentation doesn't seem to tell what is the algorithm it is using (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blur.html). Is there any place we can find more detailed information if wanted?

Comment: I think the page you reference explains exactly what it does.

Comment: Sorry I missed it, probably because it's nested in one of the nodes. Or is it systematic that it'll always be in the same node, `Properties and Relations`?

Comment: Properties and relations is always a worth a look to understand what Mathematica functions do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Properties & Relations it says

> Blur is equivalent to GaussianFilter with radius r, width σ=r/2, and
>   "Fixed" padding

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blur.html

Comment: Will it always be in Properties & Relations, for other function as well? More systematic in a way?

Comment: Looks like it is.